# Is there any way to find how many new accounts were created today?

Tags: discussion, new-users

Is there any way to find how many new accounts were created today?

On the profile page we have

[image]

Comment: I guess that 'too many, and mostly puppets and homework-vamps' is insufficiently precise?

Comment: @MartinJames **Filter** by **country**. Any chance to get it

Comment: SE doesn't publish that statistic.  It can be reverse-engineered by looking at an old version of the reputation league page at archive.org.  There are 4,765,861 accounts today and 3,606,288 a year ago.  So that average out to 3,168 new accounts per day.  Not members, accounts.  It has to be compensated for day-of-week variation and the number of destroyed account so peg it at a fat three and a half thousand.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can check it using this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=66&tab=newusers&sort=creationdate

You might have to change the page number (I found it rather quickly using binary search), but right now that's where the cut-off is between one-day members and two-day members. 65 pages of 36 users each, that amounts to 2340.

[image]

Comment: Not bad but **tooooo many pages**

Comment: You're a programmer, that means you know binary search :)

Comment: Thanks it's useful for me. That's what i want. Wow!!!

Comment: @Glorfindel Being as terrible with terminology as I am, I apparently didn't know I knew binary search. I learned something.

Comment: @Jake there are two kinds of programmers, those who know binary search and those still looking for it.

Comment: This method counts new _registered_ accounts only, since cookie-based accounts are not listed under /users/. Granted, on SO most accounts are registered, since registration is required to ask questions.

Answer (score 18):

I created a query in SEDE that brings up some of this data. Keep in mind that SEDE won't include users who have been deleted, so we can make guesses based on min and max user ids:

```
select cast(CreationDate as date), count(*) As Actual, max(Id)-min(Id) As Expected
from Users 
where Id > 4999999
group by cast(CreationDate as date)
order by 1 desc
```

[link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/471001/number-of-users-created-day)

It's interesting to see the odd days where the two are wildly different, such as 23rd March that say 5k users really there, but a jump of 70k in user ids.

Comment: I think the jumps in Id's must be due to something like account merges, though I don't know (what does a merge actually do in the db?). I'd initially assumed it was an actual splurge in account creation, but that doesn't seem to be the case as Max(Id) of one date isn't guaranteed to be lower than Min(Id) of future dates.

Comment: For example, [6172204](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6172204/) created 22 days ago, but user with lower id by 1 [6172203](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6172203/) created only seven days ago.

Comment: Note that SEDE is updated once a week...

Comment: It's more likely to be a splurge in account deletion when a prolific abuser is identified.

Comment: @oran why would that cause userid's to be out of sequence with creation dates?

Comment: I was referring to when the id jump is much larger than the user jump.

Comment: @OrangeDog so was I. In cases where the range is much larger, the max of one day is typically higher than the min of (several) days afterwards.

Comment: Inactive users who have not contributed in a significant way are autodeleted, after 6 months, (I think), so that could account for the differences and jumps.

Answer (score 16):

If you just need the total account created today, you can use the API:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?fromdate=1460678400&todate=1460764800&site=stackoverflow&filter=!--YDD7Dv_qhO
```

Where:

- fromdate is 15/04/2016 00:00
- enddate is 16/04/2016 00:00
- filter is *show only total*.

Test it yourself:

```js
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      var re = /(\d+)/;
      if ((m = re.exec(xhttp.responseText)) !== null)
      {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Today\'s users :' + m[0]
      }
      else
      {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Something\'s wrong...';
      }
    }
  };
  var now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  var thisMorning = now - now % 86400;
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?fromdate="+thisMorning+"&todate="+now+"&site=stackoverflow&filter=!--YDD7Dv_qhO", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">Let's update this counter</div>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Wow it's awesome. Donna it's possible by using StackExchange API